# Control the confirm button in bootstrap confirm modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

[Confirm modal example](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-related-target)

I changed the example to a simple one. I want to call a delete function when I click on "Remove this {{item.id}}" button. The title successfully get the item.id value.

```
<h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Do you want to remove  {{item.id}}</h4>
```

But the button doesn't get the item.id value and the function doesn't work. And instead of "Remove this item.id" it's only "Remove this ", and the function doesn't get the parameter too.

```
<button type="button" id="exampleModalLabel" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="removeItem(item.id)">Remove this {{item.id}}</button>
```

What I have is this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in items">
    <td>{{item.id}}</td>
    <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="{{item.id}}">Remove this item?</button></td>
</tr>
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Do you want to remove  {{item.id}}</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="removeItem(item)">Remove this {{item.id}}</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

//And this javascript
$('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
var recipient = button.data('whatever');
var modal = $(this);
modal.find('.modal-title').text('New message to ' + recipient);
modal.find('.modal-body input').val(recipient);
});
```

I hope the info is enough. If you need some more info, please tell me.

Comment: Shouldn't removeItem(item.id) be removeItem({{ item.id }}) ?

Comment: Nope, same result... It doesnt even get it on the innerHTML too...

Comment: Does the Modal appear on the screen?

Comment: You can always make a workaround by setting the value through javascript. Set the value in JS: var item = '{{item.id}}'; An then in your function for modal: modal.find('.modal-body button').attr("ng-click", "removeItem("+item+")");

Comment: @PaulMoldovan I tried that, But it's not working still...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this:

```
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="button" id="removeButton" class="btn btn-primary">Remove this <span id="itemid"></span></button>
</div>

//JS
$('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
var recipient = button.data('whatever');
var modal = $(this);
modal.find('.modal-title').text('New message to ' + recipient);
modal.find('.modal-body input').val(recipient);

modal.find('#itemid').html(recipient); // add this
modal.find('#removeButton').attr('ng-click', 'removeItem('+recipient+')'); // add this
});
```

Comment: All seems fine, but the function doesn't want to trigger... And I don't know why... I am trying to debug it, to see what goes wrong, but it seems like the function just doesn't trigger....

Comment: The one for the <span> works fine... It even add the "ng-click="removeItem(myItem)" too, but when I click, the function doesn't trigger...

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Unfortunately I don't know AngularJs and I can't help you there. Here is a link that might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27897175/ng-change-ng-click-dont-work-with-data-toggle-buttons-since-v1-3-0

Answer (score 2):

Your modal is out of `items` scope. You need to assign your `item` to some temp variable inside controller. You should use `ng-click` to achieve that, something like this `ng-click="tempItem = item"`. You probably also have to edit your `removeItem` function.

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in items">
    <td>{{item.id}}</td>
    <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="{{item.id}}" ng-click="tempItem = item">Remove this item?</button></td>
</tr>
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Do you want to remove  {{tempItem.id}}</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" id="exampleModalLabel" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="removeItem(tempItem)">Remove this {{tempItem.id}}</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

//And this javascript
$('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
var recipient = button.data('whatever');
var modal = $(this);
modal.find('.modal-title').text('New message to ' + recipient);
modal.find('.modal-body input').val(recipient);
});
```

Comment: Even though modal is out of items it still manages to get the item.id in
`<h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Do you want to remove  {{item.id}}</h4>`
Why it doesn't get it in 
`<button type="button" id="exampleModalLabel" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="removeItem(item)">Remove this {{item.id}}</button>`

Comment: I don't think that it manages to get `item.id` in `h4`, you're just changing `h4` content with jquery `modal.find('.modal-title').text('New message to ' + recipient);`

Comment: actually yes, my bad!